# Elixir/Phoenix handling erlang errors

Tags: error-handling, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using `System.cmd` command to work with a file. However if the files is not found on the system, it raises [ArgumentError](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/System.html#cmd/3), specifically `Erlang error: :enoent`. 
How can I handle this error with the case function? Here is my code so far:

```
case System.cmd(generate_executable(settings), ["start"]) do
  {output, 0} ->
    IO.inspect("Start successful")
  {output, error_code} ->
    IO.inspect("Start failed")
end
```

This cases work for mistakes from OS (whether is starts or not), but not for the erlang errors, resulting in phoenix telling me about :enoent. 
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to use `try`/`rescue`.

```
try do
  case System.cmd(generate_executable(settings), ["start"]) do
    {output, 0} ->
      IO.inspect("Start successful")
    {output, error_code} ->
      IO.inspect("Start failed")
  end
rescue
  error ->
    IO.inspect(error)
end
```

When the executable does not exist, you should see `%ErlangError{original: :enoent}` printed by the `IO.inspect` in `rescue`.

Comment: Hey @Dogbert, thank you for your answer! I didn't know about try/rescue, will take a look now.